# Syntax of where block

Tags: haskell, syntax, notation

I'm reading Programming in Haskell by Graham Hutton and it gives the following code in Chapter 13:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Char

{- some code omitted -}

newtype Parser a = P (String -> [(a, String)])

item :: Parser Char
item = P (\ input -> case input of
                     []   -> []
                     x:xs -> [(x,xs)])

three :: Parser (Char,Char)
three = pure g <*> item <*> item <*> item
        where g a b c = (a,c)
```

I'm having a hard time understanding the last line

```
where g a b c = (a,c)
```

I understand that this line exists because three has type Parser(Char, Char) but what does g a b c represent? How is g a b c syntactically valid? I'm used to seeing where in cases like

```
f :: s -> (a,s)
f x = y
   where y = ... x ...
```

where each symbol x and y appear before the where declaration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It  is the syntax to declare a function. It is the equivalent to

```
 where g = \a b c -> (a,c)
```

`g` is a function which takes 3 arguments and returns a tuple

Answer (score 2):

> How is `g a b c` syntactically valid?

It's valid for the same reason same definition on the top-level of the module would be valid. The difference between definitions in `where` and top level is just that you have variables bound in function's head (e.g. `x` in your last example) in scope and can use them on the right side, but this doesn't mean you *have* to use them.